# Декоратор, который выводит время выполнения функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь написать декоратор, который выводит время выполнения функции.Подскажите пожалуйста что не так.Спасибо

```
import time


def time_of_function(function):
     def wrapped(first, second):
         start_time = time.clock()
         function(bin(int(str(first), 2)+int(str(second), 2)))
         print(time.clock() - start_time)
     return wrapped

@time_of_function
def time_of_func(function):
    print(function(111,0000))
```

Comment: При рекурсивной функции будет принтовать время много раз

Answer (score 5):

Видимо, вы хотели сделать такое. Основная ошибка: в декораторе не нужна реализация функции. Логика функции - внутри функции.

```
import time

def time_of_function(function):
    def wrapped(*args):
        start_time = time.perf_counter_ns()
        res = function(*args)
        print(time.perf_counter_ns() - start_time)
        return res
    return wrapped

@time_of_function
def func(first, second):
    return bin(int(first, 2) + int(second, 2))


print(func("111", "0000"))
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое.Стало понятнее...кажется))!!!Но не совсем понял зачем return res. Буду ковырять дальше.Спасибо

Comment: @Валерий, чтобы вернуть значение вызывающему коду. Можно, конечно, делать вывод (`print`) значения прямо в вызываемой функции, но это уже побочный эффект, который в некоторых случаях может усложнить понимание кода. Лучше исходить из того, что функция должна посчитать значение и вернуть его наружу. А что с ним делать дальше, уже следующий вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы очень понятно объяснили!